# Trace of the language on the object code

Tags: compiler-construction, programming-languages, object-code

Is it possible to look at an object code and tell which language has been used originally to produce it?  or does the language leaves a trace or a stamp on the object code ? do the compilers of various languages use a fixed format for a given ISA to develop the object code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no general algorithm, but in practice it is often possible. Usually you can just look at the libraries that the application depends on - if a Windows application depends on [msvcrt.dll](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Windows_library_files#Msvcrt.dll), for example, then there's a high chance that it's a C or C++ program compiled with Visual C++. Sometimes a compiler leaves traces of evidence in the `.data` section. Here is what I see when opening a "Hello, World!"-like Haskell binary (compiled with GHC) in a hex editor:

[image: GHC]

Here's what GCC's "copyright notice" looks like:

[image: GCC]

A trained eye can even recognize compiler version by looking at disassembly (every compiler optimizes code slightly differently and has its own implementation quirks). If you need to automate this, I suggest looking at machine learning techniques.

Comment: +1 In fact there were heuristic tools to tell which compiler was used back in DOS days. I'm sure there are some still around.

Answer (score 1):

Nope. x86 is x86- once it's in that format, there's no trace of the original language.